# How can I check if three or more results are statistically identical?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test, multiple-comparisons

I conducted several experiments (for the moment 3, but there will be more in the near future), where in each experiment I made several measurements. I know (from previous experience) that the result roughly normally. For each experiment I have the mean value and the standard deviation of the results. I am trying to test the hypothesis that all three results are identical, with p% accuracy. When I had only 2 results I used the t-test and found that there was no significant difference between them, but now that I have 3 I am a bit lost.

Could you please help with this?

Comment: The ANOVA tag you used suggests you already know the answer to this question.

Comment: I got the general idea from a search in the web that that's the direction, but I can't figure out how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I found a source online that does a comprehensive example, along with detailed explanation on how to do an ANOVA test for a case very similar to this one.

Source is attached:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3916511/